# GCP - get project NAT GW's

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

We have account on GCP which contain valid cloud Nat, now we want to get those values via
GCP sdk, I've tried the following and get empty response (maybe I use the wrong API and it not `ListExternalVpnGatewaysRequest`)

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    compute "cloud.google.com/go/compute/apiv1"
    "google.golang.org/api/iterator"
    computepb "google.golang.org/genproto/googleapis/cloud/compute/v1"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    c, err := compute.NewExternalVpnGatewaysRESTClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    defer c.Close()
    proj := "dev-proj"

    req := &computepb.ListExternalVpnGatewaysRequest{
        //Filter:               new(string),
        //MaxResults:           new(uint32),
        //OrderBy:              new(string),
        //PageToken:            new(string),
        Project: proj,
        //ReturnPartialSuccess: new(bool),
    }
    it := c.List(ctx, req)
    for {
        resp, err := it.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
        // TODO: Use resp.
        _ = resp
        fmt.Println(resp)
    }
}
```

I need to get the following values using GCP GO SDK

[image]

**update**

I tried the following as-is and I got error

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "google.golang.org/api/compute/v1"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    project := "my-proj"

    region := "my-region"
    ctx := context.Background()

    computeService, err := compute.New(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    req := computeService.Routers.List(project, region)
    if err := req.Pages(ctx, func(page *compute.RouterList) error {
        for _, router := range page.Items {
            // process each `router` resource:
            fmt.Printf("%#v\n", router)
            // NAT Gateways are found in router.nats
        }
        return nil
    }); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

}

Error is: ./main.go:16:36: cannot use ctx (type context.Context) as type *http.Client in argument to compute.New
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A VPN Gateway is not the same as a NAT Gateway.

Use this code to list routers. Within the list of routers, is the NAT Gateways

```
import "google.golang.org/api/compute/v1"

// Replace with valid values for your project
project := "my-project"
region := "my-region"

ctx := context.Background()

c, err := google.DefaultClient(ctx, compute.CloudPlatformScope)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

computeService, err := compute.New(c)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

req := computeService.Routers.List(project, region)
if err := req.Pages(ctx, func(page *compute.RouterList) error {
    for _, router := range page.Items {
        // process each `router` resource:
        fmt.Printf("%#v\n", router)
        // NAT Gateways are found in router.nats
    }
    return nil
}); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

[SDK Documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api/compute/v1)

Comment: Thanks, could You please add the import that you are using?

Comment: I added the import statement

Comment: I just added a link to the Go Compute SDK documentation

Comment: thanks, does it works for you? I got an error when running the code , please see my update

Comment: @Alberto I updated my answer to include the authorization section using ADC. My first answer was just the section you needed. I assumed you knew how to set up the client as I did not know which authorization mechanism you are using (service account, ADC, etc.)